DOCKER - Why new resources defined in rest api doesn't get synced in wso2 api manger and when I call the resource face 404 not found error?
Help ! I'm facing a 404 error on 4.3.0. each time I publish a new API and call it. When I restart the server it works then (so any time I need to add an API, I first add it and restart the server to get it ok).
in the UI we get the error :
Failed to fetch.Possible Reasons:CORSNetwork FailureURL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

On the server side we can see :
{"code":"404","type":"Status report","message":"Not Found","description":"The requested resource is not available."}

Version: 4.3.0
Docker

When I perform the same test using Linux or Windows, it works. I notice that the error is in the synchronization with Docker
Version: 4.3.0
Docker

When I perform the same test using Linux or Windows, it works. I notice that the error is in the synchronization with Docker
